# How to get types of columns and use it in c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

i want to make an insert function in access database in my c# code
and i want this function to get parameters that like columns types in my database

i tried to make a list and add types of columns in it 
but i want to know :

1- how to make types(parametrs of insert function) equal list_types

2- if i want to use my types in another code how to convert runtime types to normal types int, string

```
partial class Program
{
    public void insert(params object[] types)
    {

    }

    static List<object> list_types = new List<object>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM students";
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();



        // add columns types in list to use it in parametrs of insert function
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {

            if (reader.GetFieldType(i).Name == "Int32")
            {
                list_types.Add(new int());

            }else if(reader.GetFieldType(i).Name == "String")
            {
                list_types.Add("any value because 'new string()' throw error (i wanna type only not value)");
            }
        }

        //printing types of elements of list type

        foreach(var item in list_types)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.GetType().ToString());
        }
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader[0] + "    " + reader[1]);

        }
        conn.Close();
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You aren't working with types... you're doing this weird turn a type into a string and back into a type mumbo-jumbo.

How about skipping all that:

```
List<Type> types = new List<Type>();
for(int fieldIndex = 0; fieldIndex < reader.FieldCount; fieldIndex++) {
    types.Add(reader.GetFieldType(fieldIndex));
}
```

Then when printing them to the console:

```
    foreach(Type type in types) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{type.ToString()}");
    }
```

Comment: ok when i make this code:

types[0] variable = 13;

i get error ' cannot convert int to type :

can i convert type class to int or other types
thanks :)

Comment: No, you can not majically convert one type into another, usually.  A `Type` and an `int` are certainly not the same thing.

Comment: ohh ok :)
in top i want my insert function know types of columns and make convert them 
to parametrs i mean when i call it 
it appear like that : (if types of columns in database ( int , string))
insert(int var1,string var2)

Comment: and if data types in columns change function parametrs change too
are there any way to do that :)